# What to call an "online illustrator"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology, professions

Is there a term to refer to an illustrator who mainly posts his or her works online? I mean, a lot of illustrators started out this way, so I am curious if there's a term that we can use to refer to them.

Comment: How do they post their art? Facebook? Their blog? I think more details are needed for a good answer.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but in my native language we just call them "internet illustrators" regardless of the websites or social media they post their arts.So I was wondering if English has a term for this.

Answer (score 1):

If the artist is creating art for websites as a job, the most common terms are "[web graphic designer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22web%20graphic%20designer%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)" or just "[graphic designer](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=0afBWq3DFoi18APg-7TACQ&q=%22graphic%20designer%22&oq=%22graphic%20designer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l3j0i7i30k1l2j0i67k1j0l2j0i7i30k1j0.20592.21176.0.21344.4.4.0.0.0.0.122.416.1j3.4.0..3..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.414...0i13k1.0.5jaTTIAvXB0)", although the latter is also used for people who work with print media.

For artists who publish their own personal works online, you might try "[web artist](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=tKbBWvidMOvV0gL98pyYBw&q=%22web%20artists%22&oq=%22web%20artists%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l7j0i30k1j0i8i10i30k1j0i8i30k1.8128.9962.0.10374.2.2.0.0.0.0.108.202.1j1.2.0..3..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.202...0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.EBbLnzaqlbw)", "[internet artist](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=N6fBWoCdEov9_wTv2JiYCQ&q=%22internet%20artists%22&oq=%22internet%20artists%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l4j0j0i7i30k1l5.27430.27976.0.28300.8.7.0.0.0.0.200.952.1j5j1.7.0..1..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.1.200....0.cg4a9tCwUIE)", or "[net artist](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=YafBWu_aJ4nl0gLgqJbwAQ&q=%22net%20artists%22&oq=%22net%20artists%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l10.9330.9422.0.9566.3.2.0.0.0.0.130.192.1j1.2.0..1..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.130....0.I2K62utsJ2w)" which both return quite a few examples of usage in Google results for those terms.